# WARNING using viso2_ros mono_odometer: "The tf from '/base_link' to '/camera' does not seem to be available, will assume it as identity!"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I can run mono_odometer application properly, but I continue to get the warning showed in the title. How to fix it?
How can I set the tf from /base_link' to '/camera' ?

Kind regards.
Aldo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44212/warning-using-viso2_ros-mono_odometer:-%22the-tf-from-%27/base_link%27-to-%27/camera%27-does-not-seem-to-be-available,-will-assume-it-as-identity!%22/) by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you know the tf library? If not, read up on that.

You need to define a transform from /base_link to /camera, i.e. basically where it is mounted on the robot. If that is fixed, you can use a static_transform_publisher, otherwise define a URDF description.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on 2012-09-20**:
I know how to create a tf object , but I don't know how to set it. In particularly, I don't know how to set base_link_frame_id tf of viso2ros.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-20**:
Use a static_transform_publisher or create an urdf. You can also use a custom TransformBroadcaster if necessary.

**Comment by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on 2012-09-20**:
ok, I've used roscd tf
./bin/static_transform_publisher 0 0 2 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /camera 100

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-20**:
I'd advise to use rosrun. Also units are in meters, so 2 seems large (but might be correct)